# Show uniqueness of solution to a function with infinite limit (and sequences).

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, limits, functions

I've got a question concerning some weird kind of Lipschitz constant function, but it's an introduction course in Mathematics, so Lipschitz continuity isn't part of the course (to my knowledge). Here's the question:

**Introduction**

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a function and $a\in\mathbb{R}$. Define the sequence $(x_n)_{n\geq 0}$ by $x_0=a$ and for $n\geq 0, x_{n+1}=f(x_n)$.

Assume now that the function $f(x)$ has the following property: There is a constant $L\in(0,1)$ such that for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$ that following holds: $|f(x)-f(y)|\leq L|x-y|$.

**Already Shown / Proven**
$$|x_{k+1}-x_k|\leq L^k|x_1-x_0|$$
For all $n>m\geq 0$ the following holds: 
$$|x_n-x_m|\leq\sum_{k=m}^{n-1}L^k|x_1-x_0|$$

The sequence $(x_n)_{n\geq 0}$ is convergent (by Cauchy).

**Assignment**

Show that $z$ defined by $z=\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n$ is the unique solution of the equation:
$$x=f(x)$$

(So to prove: there is a solution, and there is at maximum one solution)

**How far i've come**

I don't really know what to do except write the following:
$$z=\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_{n-1})$$
Or:
$$f(z)=f(\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n)=\lim_{n\to\infty}x_{n+1}??$$

I don't even know if this is correct. I just need a little push to get going.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is known as the [Banach fixed-point theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_fixed-point_theorem). There is a solution to $f(x)=x$, namely $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n$, since
$$f(x) = f\left(\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n\right) = \lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_n)=\lim_{n\to\infty} x_{n+1} = x, $$
where continuity of $f$ justifies the interchange of limit. Now suppose $x'$ satisfies $f(x')=x'$. Then
$$0 \leqslant |x'-x| = |f(x')-f(x)|\leqslant L|x'-x|. $$
Since $0<L<1$, this implies that $|x'-x|=0$, and hence $x'=x$, which means that the solution is unique.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things to do in this problem:

1. Show that there *is* a $z$ with $f(z) = z$
2. Show that this $z$ is unique
3. Show that the function converges
4. Show that the function must converge to such a $z$

---

1.

First we show that such a $z$ exists. Take $b = f(0)$. There are three cases. Either $b = 0$, $b < 0$ or $b > 0$. If $b = 0$, we are done. Otherwise, look at the function $g(x) = f(x) - x$ (I'm assuming $b$ is positive for simplicity, the exact same argument and $g$ works for $b$ negative). Note that for $z$ such that $f(z) = z$, we have $g(z) = 0$. We know that $g(0) = b$, and we have:
$$
g(b/(1-L)) = f(b/(1-L)) - b/(1-L)\\
 = \big(f(b/(1-L)) - f(0)\big) + b - b/(1-L)\\
\leq |f(b/(1-L)) - f(0)| + b - b/(1-L) \\
\leq L|b/(1-L) - 0| + b - b/(1-L)\\
\leq L\frac{b}{1-L} + b - \frac{b}{1-L}\\
= \frac{bL + b(1-L) - b}{1-L} = 0
$$
which means that either $g(b/(1-L)) = 0$, and we have our $z$, or we have $g(b/(1-L)) < 0$, which means that $g$ changes from positive to negative between $0$ and $b/(1-L)$, so by the intermediate value theorem. Either way, we've proven the existence of $z$.

---

2.

As for why there is a unique $z$ with $f(z)=z$, assume there are two such points $z_1,z_2$. Then $|f(z_1)-f(z_2)|=|z_1-z_2| > L|z_1 - z_2|$, which is not allowed.

---

3.

You've proven that the sequence is Cauchy, so it does converge to some value.

---

4.

Assume the limit is some number $y$ with $f(y)\neq y$, let's say $|f(y) - y| = \delta$. By definition of limit of a sequence, there is an $N \in \Bbb N$ such that for each $n> N$, we have $|y-x_n| < \delta/2$, say. This implies that $|y - x_{n+1}| = |y - f(x_n)| < \delta/2$. But we have $|f(y_n) - f(x_n)| < L\delta/2$. Therefore
$$
|y - f(x_n)| + |f(x_n) - y| < \frac\delta2 + L\frac\delta2 < \delta = |y - f(y)|
$$
which violates the triangle inequality. Such a $y$ can therefore not be the limit of the sequence. That leaves the $z$ from above as the only available limit value, and since you know the limit exists, we are done.